# How to send file along with parameters to the controller using Ajax call in Liferay

Tags: ajax, liferay

I am using a form to send some data along with an attachment in Liferay .The problem is that i can not use serveresource for sending  file.I  need to do an ajax call to send the data to the server.But how to do that in liferay .I am posting my code

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="theme" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<theme:defineObjects/>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<portlet:resourceURL var="resourceURL"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function callServeResource(){
AUI().use('aui-io-request', function(A){
    A.io.request('<%=resourceURL.toString()%>', {
           method: 'post',
           form: {
               id: 'fm'
           }
        });
    });
}

  </script>
<form name="fm" id="fm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Full Name:<input type="text" name="fullName"/>
<br/>
Age:<input type="text" name="age"/>
<br/>
File:<input type ="file" name="fileName"/>
<input type="button" value="Submit Form Data" onclick="callServeResource()">
</form>
```

This is my controller class

```
public class MainDriver extends MVCPortlet{

@Override
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest,
        ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws IOException,
        PortletException {

    UploadPortletRequest uploadPortletRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(resourceRequest);
    String fullName = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "fullName");
    String age = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "age");
    File file = uploadPortletRequest.getFile("fileName");
    System.out.println("The value of fullName  "+fullName);
    System.out.println("The value of age  "+age);
    System.out.println("The File  "+file);

    super.serveResource(resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
}
```

}

So now the problem is that i am getting all the data except the file .

How to send all the data along with the file in controller in liferay ??

Comment: Can anyone solve this?? please help

Comment: "I cannot use serveResource but I have to use Ajax". In the portal world, the resource phase is exactly what handles this kind of requests. Please give more background as to why you can't use the resource phase. You'll definitely have to add a URL (attribute: action) to your form in order for it to be handled anywhere.

Comment: @OlafKock can you tell me the syntax how i can send one name attribute and one file to the server via resource ?

Comment: @OlafKock can you help now only the file is not going to the controler

Comment: Use uploadPortletRequest to retrieve parameter from request instead of resourceRequest.

Comment: @ParkashKumar can i use uploadPortletRequest  in servresource?because i am using serveresource

Comment: Never tried, but if uploadPortletRequest is populated using resourceRequest, then you can use it.

Comment: can you give me a way to do this stuff ??? if you have any?

Comment: Look at this one: http://www.liferay.com/web/muasif80/blog/-/blogs/uploading-files-using-ajax-via-alloyui